# Css button sliding doors

Tags: css, button

I'm trying to style a button with the css 'sliding doors' technique, but it isn't working properly. I've only got access to firefox 3 at the moment so this issue may not occur in other browsers but I would like to solve it for firefox as well.

Here's a picture of what the problem is:

http://img131.imageshack.us/img131/3559/buttons.png

As you can see the second side is lower than the first by a pixel and also is not over to the right enough. Here is the code I am using:

```
button
{
    font-weight: bold;
    border: none;
    background: top left url(../images/blue_button_left.gif) no-repeat #24AADF;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    height: 25px;
}

button span
{
    display: block;
    height: 25px;
    background: top right url(../images/blue_button_right.gif) no-repeat;
    position: relative;
}


<a href="http://localhost"><button class="important" type="button"><span>Register</span></button></a>
<button type="submit"><span>Submit</span></button>
```

How do I fix this problem? I tried relatively positioning the span using top: -1px right: -3px but then the text is mis-aligned.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the padding for the button to zero, and then playing with the padding-left and width to put the text in the right place.

```
button { padding:0; padding-left:5px; width:90px; /* total width:95px */ }
button span { ... }
```

If you look at the HTML block display: padding gets added to the overall width of the object, and the background starts in the padding area, and the right half is padded

However please take note, that **button elements are NOT suited for embeding any other nodes inside** (like span). They may work OK in the browser, but IE can make your life really hard (not to mention that as far as I know, it's not valid)

Comment: Elements inside button tags are actually valid, but not inside <input> tags.
Sorry but your solution didn't work, the padding was already set to zero. Also it needs to be a dynamically sized button not fixed-width.

But thanks for trying

Answer (score 1):

http://www.oscaralexander.com/tutorials/how-to-make-sexy-buttons-with-css.html

I just did sliding doors on a div background, and the code from this site worked perfectly.

Comment: It actually needs to be a button tag because it needs to submit a form.

Comment: Why don't you use this and sumbit the form via javascript?

Comment: Just take the code and change it to fit your needs.  I used a div class instead of an <a>, and it worked.  I think your problem lies in the padding.  You need to set the appropriate padding-left and padding-right to be the size of your smaller image.

Or do what @Vnuk said.

Comment: @Vnuk: What if the user has javascript turned off?

Comment: Did you get it, or did changing the a to a button not work? (I don't have much experience with styling buttons)

Answer (score 0):

Form elements like buttons are always hard to style, and riddled with minor bugs like these.

Instead of applying the class to the button element itself, perhaps try and apply the button's styling to an extra span element inside the actual button?

In short:

```
button {
background: white;
border: 0;
}

button div {
    font-weight: bold;
    border: none;
    background: top left url(../images/blue_button_left.gif) no-repeat #24AADF;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    height: 25px;
}

button div div {
    height: 25px;
    background: top right url(../images/blue_button_right.gif) no-repeat;
    position: relative;
}
```

And HTML:

```
<button type="submit"><div><div>Submit</div></div></button>
```

Comment: Ahh it worked perfectly. No doubt there will be bugs in IE, and I really don't care for the extra markup, but it works :)

If I don't get a better reply I'll accept your answer.

Comment: Abbylaritz' method might work as well, but that would require Javascript to actually submit a form. If the user has JS disabled, you will still need a fallback method. I think my suggested method might be a better choice, since your wishes are very simple (no transparency in the button box). Less scripting involved and less error prone.

Answer (score 0):

I use DIVs instead of buttons and have a function to build them in-place. It ends up looking like this:

[alt text http://fb.staging.moveable.com/samplebutton.gif](http://fb.staging.moveable.com/samplebutton.gif)

inline script call:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>makeButton("Log in","login()")</script>
```

---

code:

```
function makeButton(text,action) {      
    document.writeln("<a class='titleGen' href='javascript:// "+action+"' onclick='"+action+";return false'><div class='btn'><div class='btnLeft'></div><div class='btnMiddle'><div class='btnText'>"+text+"</div></div><div class='btnRight'></div></div></a>")
}
```

css:

```
a.titleGen, .btnText, .btnGText {
    text-decoration:none
}
a.titleGen:hover, .btnText:hover, .btnGText:hover {
    text-decoration:none
}

.btn {
    height:22px;
    display:inline;
    cursor:pointer;
    margin-right:5px;
}
.btnLeft {
    background-image:url(/images/bg_btnLeft.gif);
    width:3px;
    height:22px;
    float:left;
}
.btnRight {
    background-image:url(/images/bg_btnRight.gif);
    width:5px;
    height:22px;
    float:left;
}
.btnMiddle {
    background-image:url(/images/bg_btnMiddle.gif);
    width:auto;
    height:22px;
    float:left;
}
.btnText {
    color:#ffffff;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    padding-top:2px;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right:10px;
}
```